# Matlab - Alternative to figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I created a figure with 8 subplots, linked axis and so on. Because the data for the plots come from different sources, I want in the end a single file which shows all the plots (with linked axis and so on).

The created figure is about 70MB. I created the figure with 2014b on MAC as well as with 2014b on Windows7. The creating process of the figure taked just some seconds and afterwards matlab opened the figure immediately and everything worked. The problem is, that it is impossible to reopen the figure in matlab (in a instance which doesn't create the figure), it will take too long (I cancelled the opening process each time after about 10minutes)

Is there another way to achieve my desired file? Another method, alternative to figures?

Comment: Would it be possible to write a MATLAB script that 1) loads the required data e.g. from a `.mat` file and 2) applies MATLAB commands to draw the figure as desired? This might be more efficient than saving a `.fig` if there is a lot of data to plot.

Comment: Adding to the comment of @mikkola, newer versions of matlab save `.fig` files in two formats, the old (HG-1 compatible) and the new. This doubles the size of the `.fig`, though I don't know whether there's a performance cost as well. [The doc to `savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html#input_argument_compact) only says "*The 'compact' option reduces the size of the .fig file and the time required to create the file.*" See also [this recent blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2015/11/10/memory-consumption/).

Comment: there is already a .mat file. But using a matfile means that there has to be everytime running the .mat file all the required data files for the plots.

Comment: I think you may be confusing `.m` files (scripts) with `.mat` files (binary files containing MATLAB variables saved from a workspace). My point was that you could generate a binary `.mat` file containing *only* the variables that are strictly needed to generate the plot you want, and then load this file using [`load`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) and then finally *only* run the part of the script that actually draws the figure.

Comment: How much data are you plotting? The plotted data is saved in the `*.fig` file so if you have a very dense set of points it's going to take a while to open.